Verify solution to system of ODEs
Consider the following system of ODE's:
\begin{align}
\frac{dx_t}{dt}&=i_t-(r_n+\pi_t)\\
\frac{d\pi_t}{dt}&=\delta \pi_t-a x_t
\end{align}
To solve it, I have written it in matrix form:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{x}_t&=\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_t+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{i}_t
\end{align}
where:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_t&=(x_t,\pi_t)^{\top} \\
\mathbf{A}&=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & -1 \\ -a & \delta\end{array}\right) \\
\mathbf{b}&=(-r_n,0)^{\top} \\
\mathbf{i}_t&=(i_t,0)^{\top}
\end{align}
To solve it manually, I have diagonalized $\mathbf{A}$:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{E} \mathbf{D}\mathbf{E}^{-1}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\mathbf{D}&=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\\
\mathbf{E}&=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 \\ -\lambda_1& -\lambda_2\end{array}\right)\\
\lambda_1&=-\frac{1}{2}(\Delta-\delta)\\
\lambda_2&=\frac{1}{2}(\Delta+\delta)\\
\Delta&=\sqrt{\delta^2+4a}\\
\end{align}
Then I have re-written the system as follows:
\begin{align}
   \frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{y}_t&= \mathbf{D} \mathbf{y}_t+\mathbf{E}^{-1}(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{i}_t) 
\end{align}
where:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}_t=\mathbf{E}^{-1}\mathbf{x}_t
\end{equation}
Finally, I have solved the system:
\begin{align}
x_t &= \frac{\left[ -(e^{\lambda_1 t} + 1) \lambda_2 + (e^{\lambda_2 t} + 1) \lambda_1 \right] x_0 + \left[ -(e^{\lambda_1 t} + 1) + (e^{\lambda_2 t} + 1) \right] \pi_0}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} + \\
&+ \int_0^t \frac{\left[ -(e^{- \lambda_1 (u-t)} + 1) \lambda_2 + (e^{-\lambda_2 (u-t)} + 1) \lambda_1 \right] (i_u - r_n) }{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} du
\end{align}
\begin{align}
   \pi_t &= \frac{\left[ (\lambda_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + \lambda_2) \lambda_2 - (\lambda_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} + \lambda_1) \lambda_1 \right] x_0 + \left[ (\lambda_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + \lambda_2) + (\lambda_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} + \lambda_1) \right] \pi_0}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} + \\
   &+ \int_0^t \frac{\left[ (\lambda_1 e^{- \lambda_1 (u-t)} + \lambda_2) \lambda_2 - (\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 (u-t)} + \lambda_1) \lambda_1 \right] (i_u - r_n) }{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} du
\end{align}
Question:
Is there any way to check that the solutions satisfy the system of ODEs either in its matrix form of the initial system?
Attempt:
This is what I have tried but it seems the solution is not satisfied. I don't understand whether I am doing something wrong with Mathematica or whether the solution is actually wrong:
xSol[t] := (-((1 + E^(t*\[Lambda]2))*x0*\[Lambda]1) + (1 + E^(t*\[Lambda]1))*x0*\[Lambda]2 + (E^(t*\[Lambda]1) - E^(t*\[Lambda]2))*\[CapitalPi]0 + 
     (-\[Lambda]1 + \[Lambda]2)*Integrate[(((1 + E^((t - u)*\[Lambda]2))*\[Lambda]1 - (1 + E^((t - u)*\[Lambda]1))*\[Lambda]2)*
         (-r + i[u]))/(\[Lambda]1 - \[Lambda]2), {u, 0, t}])/(-\[Lambda]1 + \[Lambda]2); 
\[CapitalPi]Sol[t] := (x0*(-\[Lambda]1^2 + (E^(t*\[Lambda]1) - E^(t*\[Lambda]2))*\[Lambda]1*\[Lambda]2 + \[Lambda]2^2) + 
     ((-1 + E^(t*\[Lambda]1))*\[Lambda]1 + \[Lambda]2 - E^(t*\[Lambda]2)*\[Lambda]2)*\[CapitalPi]0 + 
     (\[Lambda]1 - \[Lambda]2)*Integrate[((-\[Lambda]1^2 + (E^((t - u)*\[Lambda]1) - E^((t - u)*\[Lambda]2))*\[Lambda]1*\[Lambda]2 + \[Lambda]2^2)*
         (-r + i[u]))/(\[Lambda]1 - \[Lambda]2), {u, 0, t}])/(\[Lambda]1 - \[Lambda]2); 
Simplify[D[xSol[t], t] == i[t] - (r + \[CapitalPi]Sol[t])]
Simplify[D[\[CapitalPi]Sol[t], t] == \[Delta]*\[CapitalPi]Sol[t] - a*xSol[t]]


A simple test would be to replace your parameters by arbitrary numbers.

I would really like to do it symbolically with Mathematica.

If you do it you will see that your solutions are wrong.

Could I kindly ask you to post the code please? Obviously the part that specifies parameter values is not needed.? I am not sure how to set it up to be frank.

Your manual solution doesn't depend on parameters it , rn ,a,... ?

@UlrichNeumann I fixed it sorry

If xSol and PiSol are the solutions, and eq1=Simplify[D[xSol[t], t] == i[t] - (r +... and eq2 = Simplify[D[\[CapitalPi]Sol[t], t]...  then eq1 qnd eq2 should be True if you replace the parameters by random numbers. Or if you have problems because of machine precision, you may subtract the right side of the equations from the left side.
